# Display a message in the following format: '{operation} {status}.'

Tags: python

> ```
> def progress(operation, value):
>     """
>     Task 3: Display a message to indicate the progress of an operation.
>
>     The function should display a message in the following format:
>     '{operation} {status}.'
>
>     Where {operation} is the value of the parameter passed to this function
>     and
>     {status} is 'has started' if the value of the parameter 'value' is 0
>     {status} is 'is in progress ({value}% completed)' if the value of the parameter 'value' is between,
>     but not including, 0 and 100
>     {status} is 'has completed' if the value of the parameter 'value' is 100
>
>     :param operation: a string indicating the operation being started
>     :param value: an integer indicating the amount of progress made
>     :return: does not return anything
>     """
> ```

This is what I have tried but still not working as it should:

```
    value= int(input())
    operation= value

    if value ==0:
      status= print("has started")
    elif value ==100:
      status= print("has completed")
    elif value >1 <99:
      status= print(f"is in progress ({value}% completed)")

    print(f"{operation} {status}")
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: What does "not working as it should" mean? Please provide expected and current output, as well as any error messages.

Comment: `status = print(...)` is not what you want. Just write `status = ...` - you're printing it at the end.

Comment: I think the line `elif value >1 <99:` doesn't do what you think it does, it should be `elif 1 < value < 99:`.

Answer (score 0):

Code had multiple issues:

1. Don't overwrite the value with `input()`. Value is already a parameter.
2. No need to name value to operation (`operation = value`), you're already given an operation and for some reason you're overwriting it.
3. Don't set the status to the result of `print()`. Just set the status to the string.
4. Optional - if the range is only between 1-100, and you check both 1 and 100, the `else:` doesn't need a condition. Rewriting your condition correctly, it should be `elif 0 < value < 100:`.

Fixed code:

```
def progress(operation, value):
    """
    Task 3: Display a message to indicate the progress of an operation.

    The function should display a message in the following format:
    '{operation} {status}.'

    Where {operation} is the value of the parameter passed to this function
    and
    {status} is 'has started' if the value of the parameter 'value' is 0
    {status} is 'is in progress ({value}% completed)' if the value of the parameter 'value' is between,
    but not including, 0 and 100
    {status} is 'has completed' if the value of the parameter 'value' is 100

    :param operation: a string indicating the operation being started
    :param value: an integer indicating the amount of progress made
    :return: does not return anything
    """
    if value == 0:
        status = "has started"
    elif value == 100:
        status = "has completed"
    else:
        status= f"is in progress ({value}% completed)"
    print(f"{operation} {status}")
```

Output:

```
>>> progress("mytask", 0) 
mytask has started
>>> progress("mytask", 50) 
mytask is in progress (50% completed)
>>> progress("mytask", 100) 
mytask has completed
```